# Should my GLSL Shader object/wrapper encapsulate loading/setting a VertexArrayObject?

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d, glsl

I am working on a 2d game in C++, with a simple rendering layer over OpenGL.

I have a wrapper for GLSL shaders and shaderprograms, these wrappers encapsulate shader objects into C++ classes and automatically handle loading/compiling/linking and using shader programs.

VertexArrayObjects, it seems to me, are basically a collection of configuration settings to use with a particular ShaderProgram.

My question is thus: Should I encapsulate VAO's within my ShaderProgram objects, or within the Sprite objects? Does a VAO change on a per-shader basis or do I need a new VAO for every type of drawable object? If the latter, do I need one VAO to draw all Sprites (each containing 4 vertices, a position/orientation etc), or one VAO per sprite object in the game?

Comment: Really the only time a VAO might be relevant to a particular GLSL program is to match buffer pointers to a specific layout required by a program. If you write all of your programs with a similar convention for attribute locations, etc. you would not need anything that elaborate.

Answer (score 2):

Vertex Array Objects are simply a container for the settings that determine where OpenGL gets vertices from. They are NOT associated with any shader; you can use the same VAO with multiple shaders, as long as the vertex attributes match up. Therefore, they should be their own, separate class.

For a 2D sprite based game, where you are mostly drawing rectangles, I recommend simply creating one VAO with the rectangle mesh, and using it whenever drawing sprites.